# Teradata tpump: How to use 2 table under one label in single UPDATE statement so that performance is not impacted

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

For a particular Table update (which was missing current ts column), I used join to add another table(let say Table A) for certain keys to find the target row to update (in Table B). But it impacted the performance badly. The record commit came down to 100-200 rec/sec to 30 rec/min. Is there any work around or alternate way.

Updating a column with new feed if and only if the time second difference between the 2 message is less than 10 second. Problem here is in 1 table I have the current timestamp but in table 2 it is not there.
Tried adding join to identify the 10 sec difference by using join with other table. Got performance impacted.
P.S. I have current time stamp in Table A and in the new feed but in Table B the Timestamp column is not available.

Comment: Additional details, such as the table DDL and the UPDATE DML or possibly the TPump script, will be required to provide a useful answer.

Comment: rebuild both tables with a primary index based on the joined keys

Comment: @access_granted primary index on both the tables are exactly same columns. Thanks

Comment: @Fred will try to add more details. Thanks

Comment: @OP, could you run the stats on both tables  and see if this made a diff?

Comment: stats already added on both the table.. no improvement in performance, this I tried earlier.